# Update To 0 when Count Is 0 Not Display Null

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am running this update query, and I was hoping it would update the table to hold a value of 0 instead of displaying NULL when the count is 0.  How can this be updated to force the table so show a 0 when the count returned is 0?

```
set @sql = 
  'UPDATE cra
  SET mastercounts = te.LC
  FROM #tbl_test As cra
  JOIN (
        select 
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN recordID < 1 THEN 0 ELSE recordID end) As LC
        ,employeename
        from productioninformaiton
        where salestatus = (''Approved'', ''Shipped'')
        Group By employeename
  ) As te 
  ON cra.[StoreName] = te.[StoreName]
  AND cra.[employeename] = te.[employeename]'
Exec (@sql)
```

Comment: maybe "recordID" returns null in some cases, and therefore count(null) will return null ? try ISNULL(recordID, 0) inside your case statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the field "recordID" is returning NULL in some cases, which makes COUNT(NULL) return NULL as well. Try replacing

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN recordID < 1 THEN 0 ELSE recordID end) As LC
```

with

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN ISNULL(recordID, 0) < 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(recordID, 0) end) As LC
```